# Refresh pulled data from json PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to add something on my site, and i stucked. I want to refresh "live" if there's change for example USD Price on JSON I'm pulling from coinmarket. So somehow I need to check if there's change, pull it and live reload on my website showing it in different color, for example RED if there's change.

It's showed on this website http://lrandomdev.com/demo/crypto/ (Live market view)

If anyone can help me with this. On demo (http://lrandomdev.com/demo/crypto/) they're using socket.io for live showing.

I can reload php file with ajax, but that's not what I need , I need to refresh BTC PRICE only for example, and if there's change show it different color.

```
<table id="coini" class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
      <th scope="col">USD Price</th>
      <th scope="col">BTC Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Market (USD)</th>
     <!-- <th scope="col">Available</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
      <th scope="col">Max</th>
      <th scope="col">Change(1h)</th>
      <th scope="col">Change(24h)</th>
      <th scope="col">Change(7d)</th>
      <th scope="col">Updated</th>-->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
<?php   
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$url ='https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?start=0&limit=11';
$data = file_get_contents($url); 

$characters = json_decode($data); 

foreach ($characters as $character) {
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<th scope="row">' . $character->rank  .' - '. $character->name .'</th>';
       echo '<td><span class="sprite sprite-'.strtolower($character->name) .' small_coin_logo"></span>' . $character->symbol . '</td>';
       echo '<td id="price_usd">' . $character->price_usd . '</td>';
       echo '<td id="price_btc">' . $character->price_btc . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $character->market_cap_usd . '</td>';
        /*echo '<td>' . $character->available_supply . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->total_supply . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->max_supply . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_1h . '%</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_24h . '%</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->percent_change_7d . '%</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $character->last_updated . '</td>';*/
    echo '</tr>';
    }
 ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you considered using websockets to your clients and get data from server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for changes with JavaScript/jQuery, then I wouldn't bother pinging the API and printing the data with PHP in the first place. Check the API and display it on the front end. Hold the data in a javaScript variable, and iterate through the values and check them against new data.

Getting the new data is another issue. You can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to check the data on a semi-regular basis. Getting the data "live" would require having an active connection to some service that could push the data to the browser when something changed. That would have to be accomplished with a socket connection. But you may have trouble finding that kind of thing as a free service.